# Need help to cut squid logs

Tags: linux, shell

I'm having trouble trying to get only ip addresses with cut:

```
cat access.log | cut -d ' ' -f5
```

I got a lot of blank lines and few ips. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you paste a few lines from the acccess.log file and also your expected output? It`ll help validate the answers.

Comment: [The squid access.log file format is user-definable](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs#access.log).  You will get a much better answer if you don't ask us to guess what format you are using.  As rahul says, show some sample lines that illustrate the problem that you are having.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to ignore blank lines, you can remove them with sed as below and then use your cut command.

To remove blank lines:

`sed '/^$/d' access.log | cut -d ' ' -f5`

To remove lines with just spaces/tabs

`sed '/^\s*$/d' access.log | cut -d ' ' -f5`